# Apps Script: Want to auto-insert a checkbox to first column cell of new row

Tags: google-apps-script

*Setup:*
Google Sheets with a sidebar form

**My Objective:**
When I click the "Add" button on my Sidebar Form, I want to:

1. auto-generate a new row
2. auto-populate that new row with the form inputs
3. auto-insert a checkbox in the first cell of that new row

**My Challenge:**

I'm having difficulty getting that third step to work: "Auto-insert a checkbox in the first cell of that new row".

In the example shown in the attached picture, after clicking the "Add" button on my sidebar form...my inputs populated correctly in a new row. The checkbox DOES render, however, it renders on the active cell where I last clicked my mouse. It doesn't auto-insert into "A25", the first column of that new row.

[Spreadsheet screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTz69.png)

This is my code that adds the new row:

```js
function addNewRow(rowData) {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Home Maintenance");


  ws.appendRow([rowData.status,rowData.task,rowData.location,rowData.frequency,rowData.month]);
 
}
```

Here is my checkbox function code:

```js
function insertCheckbox(){

  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();

  var activeRange=sh.getActiveRange();

  var checkbox=SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireCheckbox().setAllowInvalid(false).build();

  activeRange.setDataValidation(checkbox).setValue(false);

}
```

Here is the script from my html file:

```js
<script>

  function afterButtonClicked() {

    var task = document.getElementById("task");
    var location = document.getElementById("location");
    var frequency = document.getElementById("frequency");
    var month = document.getElementById("month");
    var rowData = {
      status: status.value,
      task: task.value,
      location: location.value,
      frequency: frequency.value,
      month: month.value
    };
    google.script.run.insertCheckbox();
    google.script.run.addNewRow(rowData);
  }

document.getElementById("mainButton").addEventListener("click", afterButtonClicked);

</script>
```

I'm very new to coding. I think that part of the problem is that I'm using the getActiveRange() method within the insertCheckbox() function. My instinct keeps pointing to appendRow() withing my addNewRow() function, and I want to set CHECKBOX as the value for "status". I don't know which direction to take. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
function insertCheckbox(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getActiveRange().insertCheckboxes();
}
```

[ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#insertCheckboxes())

Comment: Thanks, I tried that code. The checkbox renders, but it's taking it's range position from the active cell.  So, if I click my mouse on "A28" and then click the "Add" button on the sidebar form, the checkbox renders in cell "A28" instead of "A25", which is the next available row.  Additionally, the data from the form, render one row below the row where the checkbox renders.  If I run the form without the insertCheckbox() function...the input data from the form go exactly where they should go; B25, C25, D25, E25.